# Letter Templates Pre Populate with Membership Fields

Tags: templates

I have email and letter templates that has the following

{contact.first_name} {contact.last_name}

{contact.contact_id}

{membership.end_date}

Now all these only show when you search for memberships and print from the search.  The membership end date does not show when the 'print pdf' option is selected from the contact.

Is there anyway they can all show when you go to print from pdf on the contact.

thanks,
andy

Answer (score 1):

you need to write an Extension for the membership tokens to be available in the contact summary  - please use the below link to know more

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension

if you need more help please let me know - thanks

Answer (score 1):

As CiviCRM allow to have multiple Membership at the same time, there is no way for CiviCRM to understand what you want when selecting the token {membership.end_date} in the context of a contact.

Is there a reason why you want to do this in the contact search rather than the membership search ?

If you want to limit the contact by some criteria not available in the membership search, i recommend that you use `Advanced search`, select your criteria and set `Membership` in `Display Results As`. You will then have all the action usually available for membership.

[image]